# How to correctly return a type object in F#?

Tags: f#

I am learning F# and I am struggling with a simple function that should return a simple record like so:

```
// functions that return a record

type opResult = {value:float; op: string}

let doMath (arg1:float, arg2:float) = 
  let r =
   if arg1 < 0 || arg2 < 0 then
    {value=-1.0;op="invalid"}
   else 
    {value=arg1+arg2;op="add"}
  r
 
// let result = doMath (4.1, 5.9)
printfn $"result={doMath (4.1, 5.9)}"
```

The F# compiler returns an error FS0740 (Invalid record, sequence or computation expression. Sequence expressions should be of the form 'seq { ... }')

Even ChatGPT says the code is ok;)

What are I am doing wrong?

(the indent should be ok)

Comment: "Even ChatGPT says the code is ok;)". For what it's worth, I have never had ChatGPT give me F# code that compiles, much less work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change 0 to 0.0, as you are comparing floats to ints. Then, your code will work if you put a space between "value" and "=". This might be a compiler bug.

Here's how I would write your code using more conventional casing and use of spaces, and dropping the unneeded type annotations (so, IMO, it's more readable).

```
type OpResult = {
    Value: float
    Op: string
}

let doMath (arg1, arg2) = 
    let value, operation =
        if arg1 < 0.0 || arg2 < 0.0 then 
            1.0, "invalid"
        else 
            arg1 + arg2, "add"
    { Value = value; Op = operation }
```

Comment: I would haved looked for hours on this without sering what was wrong and thanks for pointing out the improved syntax.

Comment: After I actually compiled the small example it turned out that only the missing space before the minus sign was responsible for the error. The C# compiler has no problem with that expression.